# imprimir matriz em phyton

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como fazer para imprimir uma matriz [[2,3],
                                                       [4,6]]
por exemplo, na forma de linha em baixo de linha sem usar import

Comment: print('\n'.join(l for l in matriz))

Answer (score 1):

**Primeiro modo**

```
matriz = ((2, 3), (4, 6))
for linha in matriz:
    print(linha)
```

O resultado disso será:

```
(2, 3)
(4, 6)
```

**Segundo modo**

```
matriz = ((2, 3), (4, 6))
for linha in matriz:
    for coluna in linha:
        print(coluna)
```

O resultado será:

```
2
3
4
6
```

Comment: Se a resposta solucionou o problema não esqueça de marca-la como a sua solução

Answer (score 1):

Isso imprimirá formatado:

```
matriz = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
for linha in matriz:
    for coluna in linha:
        print(coluna,end='  ')
    print('\n')
```